# Why NSHashTable keep reference to the pointer?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

I need a weak NSHashTable of objects and in case one object becomes nil I want that the NSHashTable automatically remove the object from its list.

Here is the code:

```
import Foundation

class Router: NSObject {
  let listeners: NSHashTable<Listener> = NSHashTable.weakObjects()
}



class Listener: NSObject {
}




let router = Router()
var listener1: Listener? = Listener()

router.listeners.add(listener1)

print("before", router.listeners.count)

listener1 = nil

print("after", router.listeners.count)
```

Anth the logs are:

```
before 1
after 1
```

Is it possible that I dont understand main purpose of a hashtable with weak references? The reason I want to do this, is in case that object loose all the strong references, that is also removed from the hashtable.

Answer (score 2):

You understand correctly, but the count getter is kind of messed up. Check out the following in playgrounds. You'll see the deinit gets called for the object once you release your strong reference, despite it being in the NSHashTable. However, the count method seems to have some kind of caching problem. You can use allObjects.count instead, which returns the right value, but the object is released correctly anyway. The dispatch after is so the object gets cleaned for sure in the next run loop "frame".

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

class Listener: NSObject {
    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}

let listeners = NSHashTable<Listener>(options: .weakMemory)

var listener: Listener? = Listener()

listeners.add(listener)

print("count:\(listeners.count) allObjects.count\(listeners.allObjects.count)")
listener = nil

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
    print("count:\(listeners.count) allObjects.count:\(listeners.allObjects.count)")
}
```

Output:

```
count:1 allObjects.count:1
deinit
count:1 allObjects.count:0
```